# How to assign correct answers to checkboxGridItem questions in a quiz?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

One issue with using Google Forms to make a multiple choice quiz is that if a question has (for example) 3 points and 3 out of 5 correct answers, if a student only selects 2 of the 3 correct answers they will get 0 points, not 2.

The workaround for this is to use a checkboxGrid with only 1 column where each row is an answer choice.
Points can then be awarded for each correctly selected row.

I'm at a point where I want to create revision quizzes on the fly using this method, a snippet of my code that does this is here:

```
   var question = questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)];
   var item = tasks.addCheckboxGridItem();
   item.setTitle(question[1]);
   item.setRows([ question[3],question[4],question[5],question[6],question,[7],question[8],question[9] ]);
   item.setColumns(['Click if correct']);
```

I'm at a loss as to assign the correct answer and points to specific rows. I can see how to do this for a simple multiple choice question but not for this checkBoxgrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue:

[GridItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-item) and [CheckboxGridItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-grid-item) currently don't support scoring. You cannot assign correct answers and points for these Items using Apps Script (e.g. [createChoice(value, isCorrect)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-item#createChoice(String,Boolean)), [.setPoints(points)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-item#setPoints(Integer))), nor retrieve this information (e.g. [.isCorrectAnswer()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/choice#isCorrectAnswer()), [.getPoints()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-item#getPoints()), [.getScore()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getScore())).

#### Feature Request:

There's currently a Feature Request related to this in Issue Tracker:

- [Allow user to get points and gat score of a GridItem](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142531514)

I'd suggest you to click the star on the top-left of the page in order to keep track of this and to help priorizing it.

#### Workaround:

In the meantime, your only options would be to use the UI instead, or to write a grading function yourself, as explained in the referenced issue:

> - Find your [Grid Item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getresponses) and grab it's [ItemResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response).
> - Then get the [response array](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getresponse).
> - Compare it to some grading function you create.
> - Return a score and use that number instead.

Of course, this workaround wouldn't add the scoring system to the Form itself, but it would be a way to handle quiz points programmatically.

Comment: Many thanks. Was not aware of this issue tracker, I have bookmarked it & I'll make a grading function in the future but for now will work with basic multi choice.